# Creating an Array with PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a form with multiple text inputs that all have the same name. How would I process that with my PHP when the user submits the form?

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="interest"/>
```

Comment: I love how I got an immediate -4 for trying to answer [a question like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22054798/how-to-write-a-function-in-php-to-sort-an-array-according-to-number-of-occurrenc).

Comment: @NobleUplift That's rough, but 1) since it's deleted most people won't be able to see it, and 2) not really relevant here, so someone will probably eventually flag your comment and it (and this) will likely be removed for being too meta.

Comment: @NobleUplift Reading the comments it looks as though you got the answer incorrect the first time round though?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've assumed you're using `POST`.

You would use

```
<input type="text" name="interest[]">
```

Then on the post page, you could use:

```
foreach($_POST['interest'] as $i){
    echo $i. "<br>";
}
```

or whichever method you wanted to use to get the `POST` data.

You could also do something like:

```
<input type="text" name="interest[music]"/>
<input type="text" name="interest[food]"/>
```

You can then call this data by using:

```
<?php echo $_POST['interest']['music']; ?>
```

Comment: Don't you need quotation marks around `interest[]`?

Comment: Thanks @BeatAlex for the improvement(s); this was already a good answer. Worth each upvote!

Comment: Hyperlink for you, because citations are cool: http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="text" name="interest[]"/>
```

Comment: Add some PHP code and better explain your answer to the OP.

Comment: -1 This answer desperately needs an explanation, a hyperlink, *something* to help OP know what the magic square braces do.

Answer (score 2):

You should add square brackets. This triggers PHP to put them in an array like this:

HTML

```
 <input type="text" name="interest[]"/>
 <input type="text" name="interest[]"/>
```

PHP

```
//Get values
var_dump($_POST['interest']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use brackets in your `input` field to create an array of `POST` values:

```
<input type="text" name="interest[]"/>

<?php
var_dump($_POST['interest']); // will be an array
?>
```